# Importing gridster TypeScript definitions

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, typescript-typings, gridster

I started a fresh ionic project and installed `gridster.js` with `npm install gridster` and `npm install @types/jquery.gridster` in the projects root directory. But I cannot import the installed definitions. I'm using the following statement:

`import { Gridster } from '@types/jquery.gridster';`

I think this import statement should work, but it does not. VScode tells me `/home/user/git/Project/node_modules/@types/jquery.gridster/index.d.ts"` is not a module, but what else should I import?

Also `gridster/` and `@types/jquery.gridster/` are present in my projects `node_modules/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The gridster types are global. You should not need any import for them to be picked up:

```
// @ts-check

/** @type {Gridster} */
const g = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is happening because `@types/jquery.gridster` is indeed not a module.  `@types/jquery.gridster` defines a series of interfaces, but doesn't seem to use an `export` command, so Typescript doesn't treat these interfaces as an importable module. In the Typescript file consuming `$(...).gridster`, I had to add these lines to make it work:

```
/// <reference types="jquery"/>
/// <reference types="jquery.gridster"/>
```